# python osx terminal thread with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, wxpython, subprocess

I have a program in Python that uses subprocess and Popen, however when I run a particular binary, an iOS tool called itnl/itunnel, it keeps the terminal window open for logging purposes and therefore I cannot write any further commands to that terminal such as the ssh command.

I have played around with various options including creationflags that I found in another SO thread but it didn't seem to work on OSX.

Running OSX and python 2.7 on homebrew install.

```
if ("iPhone" in stdout or "iPad" in stdout):
        self.progressBox.AppendText('Device found. Starting iTunnel\n')
        cmd = toolsDir + "/itnl --iport 22 --lport 2222"
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout = p.communicate()[0]
        if "Device connected" in stdout:
            cmd = "ssh -p 2222 root@127.0.0.1"
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Once itunnel runs it sits there waiting for connections from the device like below:

```
 [INFO] Waiting for new TCP connection on port 2222
 [INFO] Waiting for device...
 [INFO] Device connected: 6a0a098xxxxxxxx3cb2ef9ef6205
```

(this is when you type 'ssh etc etc' to complete the connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way round my issue by sending any output to dev/null and backgrounding the process:

```
./itnl --iport 22 --lport 2222 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

not ideal as I now can't get the stdout to see if a device has connected but it returns me to the terminal prompt and allows further commands.

Answer (score 0):

`p.communicate()` will block until the process has terminated so it can return all of the output from that process. You want to use it in a non-blocking mode, searching for that here on SO should turn up some good examples.

You may also want to take a look at using the `pexpect` module.

Comment: this is good advice, but even using pexpect the window is still held open by the program for logging purposes and so doesn't really help me open another terminal or my issue